# bash - gzip files that are not ending in ".gz"

Tags: bash, gzip

How can I gzip files in a directory while skipping already gzipped files without error or warning message?

I've already tried `gzip *` , `ls | grep -v gz | xargs gzip`  but they throw warning messages about already gzipped files.

Comment: Note that questions that are more about general-purpose usage of UNIX tools than about software development specifically are often a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
gzip !(*.gz)
```

...or, if you need to be able to recurse into subdirectories, `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.gz' -exec gzip -- {} +
```